# Aweber email template, In outlook the width is messed up

Tags: css, email, templates, outlook, aweber

We are trying to make this work in outlook as well, but the solutions I've found online aren't working. The email in outlook has a width about 1500px.
Does anyone know a solution?
The code is generated in Aweber. We tried many things, but nothing seems to affect the looks in outlook. :(

```
  <!-- LOGO -->
  <div style="max-width:680px;margin:auto;" class="email-container">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <table style=”word-break: break-all;” cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <![endif]-->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:680px;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td style="padding:30px 0;text-align:center;" class=""><aw:header></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <!-- BODY -->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:680px;border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden">
      <tbody>
      <!-- 1 Column Text + Button -->
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td mc:edit="lead_copy" style="padding:40px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;color:#555555;" class=""><aw:body></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <!-- Clear Spacer -->
      <tr>
        <td height="40" style="font-size:0;line-height:0;" class="">
           
        </td>
      </tr>


      <!-- 3 Cols -->




      <!-- Clear Spacer -->


      <!-- Minuscule -->

    </tbody></table>

    <!-- Email Footer -->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:680px;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td style="padding:40px 10px;width:100%;font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif;line-height:18px;text-align:center;color:#888888;" class="x-gmail-data-detectors"><aw:footer></td></tr>
      </tbody></table>
      <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
    </div>
  </center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't read the max-width value at all. If you use the max-width in combination with width:100%, that will help. Alternatively, you can use some conditional statements that will help you out with the width handling on different clients. I asked a member of AWeber's template team for you and they suggested these two:

```
    <!--[if !mso]><!--><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:600px!important; width:100%;"><![endif]-->

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600"><![endif]-->
```

Having the conditionals will let the width be 100% on mobile devices, which I assume you also want, but be 600 elsewhere.